# How do we get email read timestamp from outlook 365 using graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to get an email to read the timestamp from Outlook O365 using graph APIs.
I am getting isRead property only. I need timestamp of isRead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the Graph API doesn't expose any property when a message was read.

Even if you check MAPI [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-properties), there is no relevant property.